# save() and persist() method work differently in case of primary key generators

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently learning Hibernate. While learning about the save() and persist() methods, I read a statement that save() works outside the transaction boundaries while persist() works only inside the transaction boundaries. I am not able to understand this statement.

This concept is tough to understand as there is no clear example illustrating the above difference in code level properly.

Please refer to the below code:

Employee.class

```
package org.example;

public class Employee {

    private int employeeid;
    private String employeename;
    private String designation;

    public int getEmployeeid() {
        return employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(int employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    public String getEmployeename() {
        return employeename;
    }

    public void setEmployeename(String employeename) {
        this.employeename = employeename;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeid=" + employeeid +
                ", employeename='" + employeename + '\'' +
                ", designation='" + designation + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

App.java

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmployeeid(1);
        employee.setEmployeename("Chris");
        employee.setDesignation("Developer");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate-cnf.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.save(employee);

        Employee e2 = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class,1);
        System.out.println(e2.toString());


        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

mapping file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.example.Employee" schema="employee">
        <id name="employeeid" column="eid">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="employeename"/>
        <property name="designation"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

You can see that in the mapping file I am generating the primary key using the generator. If I call the save method, I am getting the below lines in output:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists employee.Employee
Hibernate: create table employee.Employee (eid integer not null auto_increment, employeename varchar(255), designation varchar(255), primary key (eid))
Oct 22, 2023 1:21:09 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into employee.Employee (employeename, designation) values (?, ?)
Employee{employeeid=1, employeename='Chris', designation='Developer'}
```

If I remove the primary key generator in the mapping file and manually assign the primary key in the App.java file:

```
employee.setId(1);
```

Mapping file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.example.Employee" schema="employee">
        <id name="employeeid" column="eid">
          <!--  <generator class="native"></generator>-->
        </id>
        <property name="employeename"/>
        <property name="designation"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then if I run the App.java, the save() method is not doing the insertion, i.e. the insertion command is not printing in the console. I am getting the following output with out the primary key generator.

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists employee.Employee
Hibernate: create table employee.Employee (eid integer not null, employeename varchar(255), designation varchar(255), primary key (eid))
Oct 22, 2023 1:24:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Employee{employeeid=1, employeename='Chris', designation='Developer'}
```

Why is the insert command not present?

Same thing I tried for persist() method too..

If I change save to persist in App.java

```
session.persist(employee);
```

And the run the file with the primary key generator, the insert command is not printing. This is expected as persist() does not work outside the transaction boundaries.

This is the output I am getting and the exception is clear as object has not been moved to persistent state.

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists employee.Employee
Hibernate: create table employee.Employee (eid integer not null auto_increment, employeename varchar(255), designation varchar(255), primary key (eid))
Oct 22, 2023 1:29:35 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: select employee0_.eid as eid0_0_, employee0_.employeename as employee2_0_0_, employee0_.designation as designat3_0_0_ from employee.Employee employee0_ where employee0_.eid=?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.example.Employee.toString()" because "e2" is null
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:28)
```

If I remove the primary key generator in mapping file and manually assign the primary key and if I call the persist() method, then it works, it is moving the object to the persistent state even outside the transaction boundary. No null pointer exception in this case.

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists employee.Employee
Hibernate: create table employee.Employee (eid integer not null, employeename varchar(255), designation varchar(255), primary key (eid))
Oct 22, 2023 1:32:08 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Employee{employeeid=1, employeename='Chris', designation='Developer'}
```

So my questions are:

1. What is meant by a transaction boundary?
2. The save() method is printing the insert statement in console when I am using primary key generator, but it is not printing the insert statement when I am manually assigning the primary key. Why is that so?
3. The persist() method is not working outside the transaction boundaries. This statement holds true when I am using primary key generators, but if I am using the same persist() method outside the transaction without the primary key generators then it works by moving the object to persistent state even outside the transaction boundary. Why is it working in this way?

Please help in clarifying the above questions as these methods are behaving differently when used with and without the primary key generator.

Don't mark this question as duplicate, in this question I have asked very specific question related to behaviour of save() and persist() wrt Primary Key generators.